# Can't get port forwarding to work

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I want to access multiple *ESP8266* in my home network from an outside network. 
The problem I'm facing is, although I've forwarded some ports on my router I'm not able to access it from outside networks.

I have created an account with **noip.com** to get a dynamic DNS domain and saved it in my router too.

But I still can't talk to my ESP or any devices for that matter. I called my ISP about opening ports, they said for that I have to call my local operator to assign me a live IP and then again call the ISP to open the desired ports.

So I wanted to ask if this really works like that? Because I have seen in many forums, blogs, videos that port forwarding can be done from my end. So why do I need to call my ISP for that. And even if I have to call the ISP to open ports, I already have dynamic DNS domain set up, so can I just ask my ISP to open ports without getting (or moving whatever) to live IP?

Comment: what specifically do you mean by "live" IP? start by determining that the port forwarding is working by attempting to connect (from outside your network) using your public IP address (rather than your no-ip domain name) just to simplify the problem.  Generally speaking, the owner of a router can forward ports, but they may be doing things upstream like using Carrier Grade Nat, filtering non-standard ports incoming, or locking down the router to prevent your access.

Comment: I suspect that your ISP is using carrier grade NAT.  Search that up.

Comment: superuser is crazy and published my answer twice !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the ESP has a service attached to the desired port. For example if the port is XXXX, and the IP adddress of the ESP is `a.b.c.d` then connect to `a.b.c.d:XXXX` and check that everything that should work is working.

Now, that you're sure that internally everything is working then, start working with accessing from outside:

- From the network where you have the ESPs check which one is your external IP. For example going to [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com). Imagine it is `f.g.h.i`.
- Your router is doing NAT to convert from the internal IP addresses as `a.b.c.d` to the single public adddress `f.g.h.i`.
- In your internet router you must have the port configuration made to reflect that everything incoming to the external interface `f.g.h.i` and port `XXXX` goes to ESP with IP `a.b.c.d` port `XXXX`, for example.
- Now, go to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and put as remote address your external IP and the remoteport. It will say if its open or closed.

  If it's **open**, it's working and you have to check your **noip.com** configuration.

  If it's **closed** then your ISP is doing something that blocks the router configuration that you've done.

Most possible cause:

1. The ISP is doing **Carrier-grade NAT**.

   Because the lack of IPv4 addresses worldwide. Some ISPs are unable to assign a public IP address to each customer and in order to give basic services, they do a **double NAT**.

   It means that your router is not receiving a public IP, but a private IP just like a bunch of their customers (houses, offices,etc.) and all the customers together pass through another NAT that puts a single unique public adddress for everyone.

   It breaks your configuration and makes impossible to get it working.

The only solution available is that your ISP gets you out from the doble NAT, assigning a public IP for your router. You have to ask them this and they'll let you know if it's available and if it will increment you month fee.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the ESP has a service attached to the desired port. For example if the port is XXXX, and the IP adddress of the ESP is `a.b.c.d` then connect to `a.b.c.d:XXXX` and check that everything that should work is working.

Now, that you made sure thatinternally everything is working then:

From the network where you have the ESPs check which one is your external IP. For example going to [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com). Imagine it is `f.g.h.i`.

Your router is doing NAT to convert from the internal IP addresses as `a.b.c.d` to the single public adddress `f.g.h.i`.

In your internet router you must have the port configuration made to reflect that everything incoming to the external interface `f.g.h.i` and port `XXXX` goes to ESP with IP `a.b.c.d` port `XXXX`, for example.

Now, go to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and put as remote address your external IP and the remoteport. It will say if its open or closed.

If it's **open**, it's working and you have to check your **noip.com** configuration.

If it's **closed** then your ISP is doing something that blocks the router configuration that you've done. Possible causes:

1. The ISP is doing **Carrier-grade NAT**.

   Because the lack of IPv4 addresses worldwide. Some ISPs are unable to assign a public IP address to each customer and in order to give basic services, they do a **double NAT**.

   It means that your router is not receiving a public IP, but a private IP just like a bunch of their customers (houses, offices,etc.) and all the customers together pass through another NAT that puts a single unique public address for everyone.

   It breaks your configuration and makes impossible to get it working. The only solution available is that your ISP gets you out from the doble NAT, assigning a public IP for your router.